How can I get a separated row instead of a CSV concated group?
I have the following query:
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS names
FROM cte t
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.orig_id
HAVING SUM(t.id = 6) > 0;

It returns something like this:
+-------------------------------------+
| names                               |
+-------------------------------------+
| iPhone 14 Promax,Samsung Galaxy A55 |
+-------------------------------------+

But I want the following result:
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id | names                               |
+----+-------------------------------------+
| 2  | iPhone 14 Promax                    |
| 3  | Samsung Galaxy A55                  |
+----+-------------------------------------+

Any idea how can I get that result?
Online Demo

https://dbfiddle.uk/4g-0gVci

With the data from your "Online Demo" link (already prepared with the recursion) there is no need for creating a list with Group_Concat() function to get the expected result.
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
  RECURSIVE tags AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'Home' AS name, NULL AS parent_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Kitchen', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Serving and reception', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Spoon', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'Digital', NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'Communication', 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'Cellphone', 6
),
products AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'Dinner Spoon Set,16 Pcs 7.3" Tablespoons' AS name, 4 AS tag_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'iPhone 14 Promax', 7  UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Samsung Galaxy A55', 7
),
cte (id, name, parent_id, orig_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, id AS orig_id
    FROM tags
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.parent_id, t2.orig_id
    FROM tags t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
)

Using same joined objects with the same ON condition as in your code you can select the product id and name directly - without creating the list that should be splitted back again. Since there is a kind of hardcoding in your list generating code ...
...
Having SUM(t.id = 6) > 0 

you could do the same in main sql's where clause like bellow (Where t.name = 'Cellphone') or (Where t.id = 7)
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select    p.id, p.name
From      cte t
Left Join products p ON(p.tag_id = t.id)
Where     t.name = 'Cellphone' 
--   OR Where t.id = 7

/*    R e s u l t :
id  name
--  ---------------------
 2  iPhone 14 Promax
 3  Samsung Galaxy A55     */

However, if you need to use your having clause condition (no metter why) then just use it as a correlated subquery in main sql's Where clause like here:
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select    p.id, p.name
From      cte t
Left Join products p ON(p.tag_id = t.id)
Where     t.id = (Select   Max(id) 
                  From     cte 
                  Where    orig_id = t.orig_id 
                  Group By orig_id 
                  Having   Sum(id = 6) > 0) 

... result is the same as above ...
See the fiddle here.

Hey, buddy here is a simplified of the real data with your query, but I don't know why it returns null, Please take a look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/fP0vLWP- .. Any idea what's wrong?!

@MartinAJ Max() is not good here ---> Use different Where clause like in this https://dbfiddle.uk/jN_ygrFs Comments in code.

Very thanks for your reply and new fiddle. But it doesn't look like getting a list of products by way of inheritance based on the tags. I'm trying to get products even by the parent tag id/name.

@MartinAJ If you want to select by parent_id then change the Where clause to parent_id = 52    ( instead of id = 135 ).
